# Python: getting the month out of a string -- This is NOT Converting string into datetime

Tags: python, regex, datetime

The title is horrible, sorry. I´m redding form a text file that has a bunch of dates in this format:

```
30/5/2015
```

and also can appear obviously with 2 numbers in the month:

```
21/12/2014
```

this is pure text, is not formatted as a date. What i have to do is to control that the month section does not exceds the number 12. This is because sometimes the date changes it´s format and appear like :

```
2/15/2015--- meaning that the second place turns to days and the first one to months
```

This are the dates that i do not need. From the text i´m getting all this dates like this:

```
fechas = list(set(re.findall(r'\b(\d+/\d+/\d{4})\b', data))) --- i use set() because sometimes the dates appear more than one time
```

I tried something like this:

```
for fecha in fechas:
    month = fecha[2:3]
```

trying to slice the string, but this wouldn´t work because of the fact that if i do this i´m getting 1 number and sometimes i need 2

Does anyone have any idea on how o do this?

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Unless there is some logic there is no way to know which is which, what should `11/12/16`  be, which is the month and which is the day?

Comment: My favorite day ever was 11/10/09, do you know what happened that day?

Comment: Why does the linked question not answer yours? Once you've converted the string to a `datetime` it is trivial to reformat the result as needed.

Comment: You can also split the string.  dates.split("/") and then index the first element to get the middle number(s)

Comment: The linked question answers everything but how to determine which field is the month and which is the day. The answer to that is either A) `try..except`, or B) impossible (see @PadraicCunningham's comment).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, good points, esp. B). I hadn't noticed Padraic's note. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for the comments. Yeah i will have to deal with the fact that is probable that i can not solve this...thanks anyways everybody